# I need a way to find internalIds of contactRole in netsuite

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitetalk

How do we get the internalId of contactrole in netsuite. I am basically trying to add a contactrole as part of contact attach to a customer record. I need to fill in the internalId attribute for contactRole below to add the proper contactRole. But I am not able to search for the internalIds of existing contactRole from the netsuite UI. Any help appreciated. Snippet Below.

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:sales="urn:sales_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
      <urn:attach>
         <urn:attachReference xsi:type="core:AttachContactReference">
            <core:attachTo internalId="1298" xsi:type="core:RecordRef" type="customer" /> 
            <contact internalId="1307" xsi:type="core:RecordRef"/>
            <contactRole xsi:type="core:RecordRef"/>
         </urn:attachReference>
      </urn:attach>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is where it can be found on netsuite UI. Setup-sales-CRM Lists